# C# Parallel.For only runs 3 request at a time

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am using the below code to get the response from the website in parallel, but it executes only 3 urls in parallel. I have to run more than 1000 urls in a single time. How to achieve this. Please advice on this. Thanks in advance.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime dtStartDate = DateTime.Now;
        Parallel.For(0, 4, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
      i =>
      {
          var task = MakeAsyncRequest("http://..../Test.aspx", "text/html");
          Console.WriteLine("Got response of {0}", task.Result);
      });
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Subtract(dtStartDate).ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static Task<string> MakeAsyncRequest(string url, string contentType)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.ContentType = contentType;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        request.Timeout = 20000;
        request.Proxy = null;

        Task<WebResponse> task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
            request.BeginGetResponse,
            asyncResult => request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult),
            (object)null);

        return task.ContinueWith(t => ReadStreamFromResponse(t.Result));
    }

    private static string ReadStreamFromResponse(WebResponse response)
    {
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            string strContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
            if (strContent != "")
                return "OK";
        }
        return "empty";
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are specifying `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4`, it would seem to me that it is behaving reasonably... but also: how many cores do you have?

Comment: Are all of your requests to the same host? If so, you may find that that's limiting you as well, due to HTTP connection pooling.

Comment: Thanks, the "Environment.ProcessorCount=4" and "Cores=2". Please advice on this.